# Как работают wait и notify для std::atomic в C++20?

Tags: c++, многопоточность, синхронизация, c++20, std-atomic

В C++20 добавили методы синхронизации потоков на основе std::atomic с использованием для них функций ожидания (std::atomic::wait) и оповещения (std::atomic::notify_one или std::atomic::notify_all).
По ссылке https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/performancecomparison-of-condition-variables-and-atomics-in-c-20 приводятся примеры использования двух переменных типа std::atomic_flag для передачи управления между двумя потоками ("ping-pong game"). Вот оригинальный код этого примера (вариант "Two Atomic Flags"):

```
// pingPongAtomicFlags.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>

std::atomic_flag condAtomicFlag1{};
std::atomic_flag condAtomicFlag2{};

std::atomic<int> counter{};
constexpr int countlimit = 1'000'000;

void ping() {
    while(counter <= countlimit) {
        condAtomicFlag1.wait(false);               // (1)
        condAtomicFlag1.clear();                   // (2)

        ++counter;
        
        condAtomicFlag2.test_and_set();           // (4)
        condAtomicFlag2.notify_one();             // (3)
    }
}

void pong() {
    while(counter < countlimit) {
        condAtomicFlag2.wait(false);
        condAtomicFlag2.clear();
        
        condAtomicFlag1.test_and_set();
        condAtomicFlag1.notify_one();
    }
}

int main() {

     auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();  

    condAtomicFlag1.test_and_set();                    // (5)
    std::thread t1(ping);
    std::thread t2(pong);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    std::chrono::duration<double> dur = std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start;
    std::cout << "Duration: " << dur.count() << " seconds" << std::endl;

}
```

Я немного изменил этот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

std::atomic_flag condAtomicFlag1{};
std::atomic_flag condAtomicFlag2{};

std::atomic<int> counter{};
constexpr int countlimit = 2;

auto time() {
  static auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
  return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start).count();
}

void ping() {
    while(counter <= countlimit) {
        condAtomicFlag1.wait(false);               // (1)
        condAtomicFlag1.clear();                   // (2)
        std::cout << time() << " sec: ping() flag1" << std::endl;
        
        ++counter;

        condAtomicFlag2.test_and_set();           // (4)
        condAtomicFlag2.notify_one();             // (3)
    }
}

void pong() {
    while(counter <= countlimit) {
        condAtomicFlag2.wait(false);
        condAtomicFlag2.clear();
        std::cout << time() << " sec: pong() flag2" << std::endl;
        
        condAtomicFlag1.test_and_set();
        condAtomicFlag1.notify_one();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  std::cout << time() << " sec: before pong() flag2" << std::endl;
  std::thread t2(pong);
  std::cout << time() << " sec: after pong() flag2" << std::endl;
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
  condAtomicFlag1.test_and_set();                    // (5)
  std::cout << time() << " sec: flag1 test and set" << std::endl;
  //condAtomicFlag1.notify_one();                      // (6)
  //std::cout << time() << " sec: flag1 notify_one" << std::endl;
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
  std::cout << time() << " sec: before ping() flag1" << std::endl;
  std::thread t1(ping);
  std::cout << time() << " sec: after ping() flag1" << std::endl;

  t1.join();
  t2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Теперь сначала запускается только поток t2 (pong), в котором происходит ожидание изменения состояния атомарного флага condAtomicFlag2. Далее главный поток засыпает на 3 секунды. После меняется состояние атомарного флага condAtomicFlag1 (test_and_set), хотя ожидающий его поток ещё не запущен. Затем главный поток снова засыпает на 3 секунды. И наконец запускается поток t1 (ping), в котором происходит ожидание изменения состояния атомарного флага condAtomicFlag1. Поскольку ранее condAtomicFlag1 уже был изменён на true при вызове condAtomicFlag1.test_and_set(), то поток t1 сразу начинает работать и запускается передача управления от потока t1 к потоку t2 и обратно в количестве раз (countlimit+1).
Вывод приложения выглядит вполне предсказуемо для меня:

```
0 sec: before pong() flag2
0 sec: after pong() flag2
3 sec: flag1 test and set
6 sec: before ping() flag1
6 sec: after ping() flag1
6 sec: ping() flag1
6 sec: pong() flag2
6 sec: ping() flag1
6 sec: pong() flag2
6 sec: ping() flag1
6 sec: pong() flag2
```

Но теперь я раскомментирую в коде функции main две строчки:

```
  condAtomicFlag1.notify_one();                      // (6)
  std::cout << time() << " sec: flag1 notify_one" << std::endl;
```

Я полагал, что это всего лишь оповещение ожидающего потока о том, что состояние атомарного флага condAtomicFlag1 изменилось. А поскольку у нас ещё не запущен поток,который будет ожидать именно этот флаг, то ничего интересного не произойдёт. Но я получил такой вывод приложения:

```
0 sec: before pong() flag2
0 sec: after pong() flag2
3 sec: flag1 test and set
3 sec: flag1 notify_one
3 sec: pong() flag2
6 sec: before ping() flag1
6 sec: after ping() flag1
6 sec: ping() flag1
6 sec: pong() flag2
6 sec: ping() flag1
6 sec: pong() flag2
6 sec: ping() flag1
6 sec: pong() flag2
```

Здесь видно, что на 3-ей секунде после вызова condAtomicFlag1.notify_one()

> 3 sec: flag1 notify_one

почему-то поток t2 вышел из ожидания в функции condAtomicFlag2.wait(false),

> 3 sec: pong() flag2

то есть по сути дождался изменения состояния атомарного флага condAtomicFlag2. Но каким образом condAtomicFlag1.notify_one() мог повлиять на ожидание совершенно другого флага в condAtomicFlag2.wait(false)?

Про std::atomic::wait написано, что "These functions are guaranteed to return only if value has changed, even if underlying implementation unblocks spuriously" (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/wait). То есть возврат из функции осуществляется только при изменении значения, даже в случае ложной разблокировки. Но я не вижу в моём случае никаких изменений condAtomicFlag2, а возврат из функции всё равно осуществляется?

Похоже я чего-то не понимаю в работе связки wait-notify? Объясните мне, что тут происходит и почему оповещение одного флага влияет на состояние другого?

P.S. Для проекта я использовал компилятор gcc version 11.1.0 (Ubuntu 11.1.0-1ubuntu1~20.04)

Comment: на godbolt'е [не воспроизводится](https://godbolt.org/z/9c6sMns4v)... у себя — проверю позже, когда gcc соберётся, но что-то мне подсказывает, что также не воспроизведётся... да и не вижу, как вообще такое может быть... на пока можешь поискать глупую ошибку (из серии не то собираешь/запускаешь/забыл сохранить перед сборкой)...

Comment: К сожалению, ошибка может и глупая, но не из серии "не то компилируешь". Результат одинаков и на gcc version 11.1.0 (Ubuntu 11.1.0-1ubuntu1~20.04) и на clang version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1. Я тоже не понимаю как такое возможно, по всей теории это абсурдное поведение. Значит где-то ошибка. Но где?

Comment: Ооо... А если по твоей ссылке выбрать gcc 11.1 вместо gcc 11.2, то моя ситуация воспроизводится. И если там последний clang 12.0.1 взять, то тоже воспроизводится. Значит дело в версии компилятора?

Comment: У вас функция time() очень *креативно* написана - нафига там statiс, и как далеко ей снесет башню при вызове из двух потоков?

Comment: @Elija, да, извини, очитался — решил, что у тебя была 11.2...

Comment: @gbg, во-первых примитивная функция time() писалась для локального применения, а не с целью оптимально работать всегда и везде. Во-вторых, чем не угодил static и с чего вдруг многопоточностью для неё станет проблемой? Как раз с этим в ней проблем нет.

Comment: Фунция явно является reentrant (просто потому что может быть вызвана из разных потоков), но при этом использует статическую переменную, что противоречит возможности быть reentrant, потому что конкурирующие потоки будут эту переменную друг другу портить.

Comment: @gbg, либо пора ложиться спать, либо... Потоки будут портить локальную статическую переменную??? А что насчёт потокобезопасности инициализации локальных статических переменных в C++11? А с какой стати после инициализации её вообще кто-то будет/сможет менять???

Comment: @Elija, тут gbg прав... «потокобезопасно инициализироваться» только при первом заходе в `time()`, а при каждом последующем она будет конкурентно меняться из разных потоков, что, вообще говоря, прямой путь к проблемам...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, видимо я туплю, но объясните мне. С какой стати статическая переменная будет инициализироваться/меняться более одного раза? Вроде же это не thread_local, то есть она одна на все потоки.

Comment: @Fat-Zer, собственно даже в примере, который мы разбирали, эта функция вызывается в трёх потоках и естественно после инициализации значение статической переменной start остаётся постоянным. Иначе бы никаких 6 секунд в конце не получилось бы.

Comment: @Fat-Zer, тьфу, это не статичксая переменная, а статическая подстава - она действительно заполнится ровно один раз. Если бы в коде где-то было еще одно присваивание, все бы действительно сломалось - ей не хватает еще и const.

Comment: да уж... стыдно признаться... но, видать, время уже действительно позднее... в третий раз в ответ на один и тот же вопрос я глупость сморозил >_<... @Elija, ты прав... мы оба ерунду пишем...

Comment: Это не статическая подстава, а запоминание времени старта)) Ещё раз напоминаю, что функция была написана просто по необходимости быстренько на время отладки и понимания почему себя так странно ведёт notify у atomic. Она не идеальна, но свои функции вполне выполняет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cудя по всему, это был [баг](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=100334) в `libstdc++` в `gcc-11.1`. В `11.2` его уже [исправили](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/346cbaf57828aef190de93271c0eb3f10c9aca61#diff-152c8ea653ec070ef53121eabdad304c07b6f7446381eedde13df2c556e752fa).

На Linux в качестве стандартной библиотеки языка с++ `сlang` по умолчанию также использует `gcc`'шную `libstdс++`, так что баги в ней у них общие.